# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar las escenas de OBS con python?

Tags: python, websocket, stream

lo que pasa es que he estado utilizando un codigo de python que con una especie de asistente virtual pueda utilizar comandos de voz para realizar combinaciones de teclas para hacer distintas cosas pero lo que pasa es que cuando intento usarlo para cambiar las escenas de OBS no funciona, pero si funciona para activar el "cmd", cambiar de pagina, etc. Pero con OBS no cambia de escena, tambien usé la libreria de obs-websocket pero a pesar que sí conectaba con el OBS no me cambiaba de escena
Este seria el codigo con la libreria PyAutogui

```
import webbrowser
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import sys
import pyautogui as robot

r = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
engine.say("Hola soy tu asistente virtual")
engine.runAndWait()

name = "alexa"

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def list():
    rec = ""
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            talk("Escuchando...")
            audio = r.listen(source)
            rec = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-ES")
            rec = rec.lower()
            if name in rec:
                rec = rec.replace(name,'')
                print(rec)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return rec

def run():
    rec = list()
    if "comando consola"in rec:
        robot.hotkey('win', 'r')
        talk("Abrir ejecutar")
    elif "comando aceptar" in rec:
        robot.press('enter')
        talk("Aceptar")
    elif "comando escena inicio" in rec:
        robot.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', '1')
        talk ("Escena INICIO")
    elif "comando stream online" in rec:
        robot.hotkey('alt', 'enter')
        talk ("Iniciar stream")
    elif "comando salida" in rec:
        talk ("saliendo")
        sys.exit(0)
    elif "comando tab" in rec:
        talk ("Cambiando página")
        robot.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
    else:
        talk("No entiendo")

while True:
    run()
```

Y este seria el codigo con obswebsocket

```
from obswebsocket import obsws, requests
client = obsws("localhost", 4444, "Contraseña")
client.connect()

try:
    result = client.call(requests.SetCurrentScene(scene_name="Inicio"))
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to change scene. Error message: " + str(e))

client.disconnect()
```

Estaría agradecido si alguien me ayudase a saber que es lo que ocurre

Answer (score 0):

Con obswebsocket debes usar `ws.call(requests.SetCurrentProgramScene(sceneName=escena))` para el cambio de escena, puedes ponerlo en una funcion:

```
def cambiar_escena(escena):
ws.call(requests.SetCurrentProgramScene(sceneName=escena))
```

yo estoy buscando la forma de activar y desactivar una fuente del obs